# Open in a new tab but not grouped with parent tab

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue with Internet Explorer 11 and a link.
So I have a webpage with a link, here is the code, classic link :

`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">My Link</a>`

So I want this link to open in a new tab, it works well with the `_blank` tag. But in IE11 the new tab is grouped with the old tab from I clicked, and I don't want that.

[image: ie11]

Is it possible by some JS or something else to force IE11 to not group the tab with the old one ? I tried with `target="_new"` too, still don't work.

Comment: It looks like this is a mechanic of IE which makes tabs group if you open them a new tab from another page. I'm not sure but it seems you can't change this behavior server side.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use window.open method to open a new tab.

Code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openInNewTab(url) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openInNewTab('http://www.google.com');">My Link</a>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why but this doesn't work, it won't open the new tab and does nothing. It works in Chrome (google.com is opened). But in IE and FireFox the link does nothing. I think the `window.open` is interpreted like a popup and blocked.

Comment: Have you ever tried to [use IE 11 Developer tools to debug whether the JavaScript function is executed](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255007(v%3dvs.85))? Try to add a debugger to check it.